# Boost serialization with recursive data structure ends up in stack overflow

Tags: c++, recursion, serialization, boost, stack-overflow

**Problem**

I'm having trouble using Boost Serialization library with a recursive data structure. More precisely, I want to serialize a matrix which is represented by nodes containing a value, and where each node has access to its neighbors (top,bottom,left,right). In order to access a node, each entry point is stored in a `vector` (that is the first and the last node of each row and and each column) . Here is the `Node` class :

```
class Node
{
private:
    int v;
    Node* left; 
    Node* right;
    Node* top;
    Node* bottom;

public:
    Node() : v(rand() % 100), left(NULL), right(NULL), top(NULL), bottom(NULL)
    {

    }

    //Potential memory leak but that's not the topic
    void setLeft(Node* toSet) { left = toSet; }
    void setRight(Node* toSet) { right = toSet; }
    void setTop(Node* toSet) { top = toSet; }
    void setBottom(Node* toSet) { bottom = toSet; }

    Node* gLeft() { return left; }
    Node* gRight() { return right; }
    Node* gTop() { return top; }
    Node* gBottom() { return bottom; }

    int gValue() { return v; }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar& v;
        ar& left;
        ar& right;
        ar& top;
        ar& bottom;
    }
};
```

Here is the `Matrix` class, with a `generateValues()` function for this example :

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int m, n;
    std::vector<Node*> firstNodesPerRow;
    std::vector<Node*> lastNodesPerRow;
    std::vector<Node*> firstNodesPerCol;
    std::vector<Node*> lastNodesPerCol;
public:
    Matrix(int m, int n) : 
        m(m), n(n),
        firstNodesPerRow(m, NULL), lastNodesPerRow(m,NULL),
        firstNodesPerCol(n, NULL),lastNodesPerCol(n, NULL)
    {
        
    }

    void generateValues()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Node* toWrite = new Node();
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    toWrite->setTop(lastNodesPerCol.at(j));
                    lastNodesPerCol.at(j)->setBottom(toWrite);
                    lastNodesPerCol.at(j) = toWrite;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstNodesPerCol.at(j) = toWrite;
                    lastNodesPerCol.at(j) = toWrite;
                }
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    toWrite->setLeft(lastNodesPerRow.at(i));
                    lastNodesPerRow.at(i)->setRight(toWrite);
                    lastNodesPerRow.at(i) = toWrite;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstNodesPerRow.at(i) = toWrite;
                    lastNodesPerRow.at(i) = toWrite;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar& m;
        ar& n;
        ar& firstNodesPerRow;
        ar& firstNodesPerCol;
        ar& lastNodesPerRow;
        ar& lastNodesPerCol;
    }
};
```

So what I want to achieve is serializing and deserializing a `Matrix`. Here is my `main` function :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int m = 10; int n = 10;
    Matrix toSerialize(m,n);
    toSerialize.generateValues();

    /*
        1) Serialize
    */
    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
    oa << toSerialize;

    std::string serialiazedData = oss.str();

    /*
        2) Deserialize
    */
    Matrix result(m,n);
    std::stringstream serializedDataStream(serialiazedData);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(serializedDataStream);
    ia >> result;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is the following : given a sufficiently large value `m` or `n`, `main` ends up with a `stack-overflow` exception. I know that's it's coming from the `serialize` method of `Node`, because in order to serialize a node, it needs to serialize the neighbors and so on... I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117697/how-to-prevent-stack-overflow-when-serializing-a-recursive-graph-structure-with) which seems to be exactly the same question. The answer is interesting as a starting point but I'm having trouble to implement it because it's not sufficiently precise. What I understand is that to solve my problem, I need to :

1. serialize the nodes in an iterative way, so that when it comes to the neighboors, the objects are already serialized and there is no `stack-overflow`;
2. serialize the topology, which is represented in my case through the pointers `top,bottom,right,left` of `Node`

I'm having trouble to actually implement this solution, because the only way I can imagine to do point 1 implies to remove the serialization of `top,bottom,right,left` in the `serialize` method of `Node`, but then I can't achieve point 2?

Edit : I made a diagram of a matrix to help reading. Note that there is not necessarily `m x n` nodes in a `m x n` matrix.

[image: Matrix example]

Edit 2 : The solution I had in mind (not working, ends up with a stack-overflow when deserializing).

```
//Class Node
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& v;
}

//Class Matrix
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& m;
    ar& n;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        Node* current = firstNodesPerRow.at(i);
        while (1)
        {
            if (current == NULL) { break; }
            ar& current;
            current = current->gRight();
        }
    }

    ar& firstNodesPerRow;
    ar& firstNodesPerCol;
    ar& lastNodesPerRow;
    ar& lastNodesPerCol;
}
```

---

**Solution**

The explanation of the solution is given in the post marked as the answer. Here is an implementation of this solution :

```
// class Node
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& v;
}

// some buffer struct
struct Neighbors
{
    Node* top;
    Node* bottom;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar& top;
        ar& bottom;
        ar& left;
        ar& right;
    }
};

//class Matrix
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const
{
    std::map<Node*, Neighbors> neighborsPerNode;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        Node* current = firstNodesPerRow.at(i);
        while (1)
        {
            if (current == NULL) { break; }
            neighborsPerNode[current] = {
                current->gTop(),
                current->gBottom(),
                current->gLeft(),
                current->gRight(),
            };
            current = current->gRight();
        }
    }

    ar& neighborsPerNode;

    ar& m;
    ar& n;

    ar& firstNodesPerRow;
    ar& firstNodesPerCol;
    ar& lastNodesPerRow;
    ar& lastNodesPerCol;
}
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // Warning ALL the nodes are browsed 2 times :
    //  1 - to deserialize neighborsPerNode (below)
    //  2 - in the for loop, to create the links between the nodes
    
    std::map<Node*, Neighbors> neighborsPerNode;
    ar& neighborsPerNode;

    ar& m;
    ar& n;

    ar& firstNodesPerRow;
    ar& firstNodesPerCol;
    ar& lastNodesPerRow;
    ar& lastNodesPerCol;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        Node* current = firstNodesPerRow.at(i);
        while (1)
        {
            if (current == NULL) { break; }
            Neighbors myNeighbors = neighborsPerNode.at(current);
            current->setTop(myNeighbors.top);
            current->setBottom(myNeighbors.bottom);
            current->setLeft(myNeighbors.left);
            current->setRight(myNeighbors.right);
            current = current->gRight();    
        }
    }
}
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble to actually implement this solution, because the only way I can imagine to do point 1 implies to remove the serialization of top,bottom,right,left" - I think this is a false assumption. Can you check your thinking against https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking

Comment: "Object tracking by address" is exactly the mechanism I planned to use. The thing is, if I leave `top,bottom,right,left` in `serialize` in `Node`, then I need to serialize the objects that these pointers refer beforehand. To do this, I can browse a matrix row by row and node by node in the `serialize` method of `Matrix` and serialize each node there. If I leave `top,bottom,right,left` in the `serialize` of `Node`, then the serialization of the very first node will have the exact same problem since the neighboors are not serialized yet. I'll add my code in OP to make it more clear.

Comment: Note that in C++ you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: The main issue is that serializing top,bottom,right,left leads to the archive serialization chasing through the pointers trying to serialize everything. `ar& firstNodesPerRow;` the first node that gets serialized will try to serialize its immediate neighbors, and those try to serialize their immediate neighbors, etc... so in the worst case you'll end up with a recursive call depth of `n*m`. An easy solution would be to just serialize the values and re-create the node structure when you need to load it again.

Comment: Is it correct that each Node simply has a random value chosen at construction that you can never change afterwards?

Comment: This is just for the minimal example

Comment: I also don't quite understand how you could leave out values in your example. Imagine a 3x3 matrix with only the center element being set. `firstNodesPerRow`, `lastNodesPerRow`, etc... would all only contain zero pointers, so there's no way to save that node. So there will always be a blind spot at the center of the matrix where you can't add nodes directly without at least filling in a few extra nodes first.

Comment: I would use any existing sparse matrix implementation with intrusive lists for row/column access.

Comment: @Turtlefight No, in this case firstNodesPerRow[1] would be a pointer on this center node (and the same goes for lastNodesPerRow[1] etc...).

Comment: @sehe Sadly I can't because of my use case

Comment: Then it's not "sadly". I can doubt it (because the chosen model seems inefficient, and not just for serialization). But I won't, because that's not the subject of a question here.

Comment: The thing is most libraries are based on "standards" (COO, CSR, CSC, BSR etc...) and the way the non zero values are stored with these formats is "not compatible" with the operations I need, one of them being merging matrices with a particular time complexity. I made [a topic there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617647/how-would-you-merge-sparse-matrices-to-create-a-new-sparse-matrix) about this if you're interested ! I'll be glad to read your solution :D !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply serialize all elements in order of the matrix and avoid the function call recursion entirely, e.g.:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar& m;
    ar& n;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        Node* node = firstNodesPerRow[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            ar & node->gValue();
            node = node->gRight();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW This works in *saving* the matrix. I think you need to specialize the serialize function in save and load versions, because for the load version you need to:

1. load n, m
2. allocate all nodes and populate the node pointer vectors in matrix
3. load all values in the same order as during saving

```
    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
    {
        ...
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ...
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

In the complicated case where nodes may be missing, the same idea applies. And you still need to split between save/load, adding allocation to load.
But it takes a lot more bookkeeping to correctly save & load again.

E.g., you could first iterate over all nodes as above but creating a map from each Nodes pointer value to an unique increasing ID number. When you save each node's value (as above row by row), also save each direction's node ID. When you load, you first make a empty map: ID -> node pointer.  Then restore nodes again row by row, while restoring neighbour pointers as well from map. Of course whenever an ID is first encountered you need to allocate a new node.

Comment: I had a similar idea in mind, but the problem is with "you need to allocate all nodes" because there is no way to know the amount of nodes a priori in the matrix (which is not necessarily `m x n`, hence the nodes) :/. A possible workaround is to store the amount of nodes in the matrix but still, you don't know a priori the "structure" of the matrix ><

Comment: Would that mean you would actually violate the figure you have drawn? Can it be different from a matrix shape of size firstnodesperrow.size() by firstnodespercol.size() ?

Comment: The matrix is always of size `firstnodesperrow.size() x firstnodespercol.size()`, however some nodes can be NULL, in that case there's not `m x n` nodes. Let's say row `i` is empty, then `firstNodesPerRow.at(i)` is NULL. You're right the diagram can confuse people I will update it.

Comment: @Spazz I added an explanation, which was too big to fit a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! This is indeed a solution, I will add my implementation in Original Post.